# Using two class with the same name

Tags: php, class, namespaces, conflict

I have two PHP apps which have twho class with the same name.
 - app1 with a class "Project"
 - app2 with a class "Project"

I have to use classes of the first app in the second one, but two class with one name cause an error ("PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Project ...").

I can't change class names.
I have to use PHP 5.2 (no namespace in PHP 5.2).

Is there a solution ?

May be :

- use the class Project
- undef this class (kind of "unset Project", is it possible with PHP ?)
- include() the 2nd class
- use the 2nd class

I don't know if it's possible with PHP (don't find any ressource about this) and I don't know a better way to manage this ...

Comment: Maybe you can use a webservice... But the easiest way is to rename the class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem recently, with (embarrassingly) Joomla. I needed to find the versions of two different installations with one script, by loading up their two "version.php" files and then reading the class properties. But, of course, they're both called "JVersion", and it's impossible to require() **both** version.php files because of it.

After much thought, I realized eval() could take the place of require(). So I just read in the contents of the version.php files and change the names of the classes, then eval() that text, and then I can access both classes with different names. I bet you'd like some code. Here's what I ended up with...

```
    $v15_txt=file_get_contents($old_dir.'/libraries/joomla/version.php');
    $v15_txt=preg_replace('/class JVersion/i', 'class JVersion15', $v15_txt);
    eval('?>'.$v15_txt);
    $jvold=new JVersion15;
    $old_version = $jvold->RELEASE.'.'.$jvold->DEV_LEVEL;

    $v25_txt=file_get_contents($new_dir.'/libraries/cms/version/version.php');
    $v25_txt=preg_replace('/class JVersion/i', 'class JVersion25', $v25_txt);
    eval('?>'.$v25_txt);
    $jvnew=new JVersion25;
    $new_version = $jvnew->RELEASE.'.'.$jvnew->DEV_LEVEL;
```

Just modify it so it loads the right two files for your needs and renames them as required. Sorry you had to wait over a year for it. :-)

It's hard to believe PHP doesn't have some kind of "undeclare($classname)" function built-in. I couldn't even solve this with namespacing, because that requires changing the original two files. Sometimes ya just gotta think outside the framework.

Answer (score 3):

Stop.

Whatever you are doing is wrong. Backup. Re-evaluate what you are doing and why.

If after that, you still need to do this. Pick an app, and do a find and replace on that class name in the app. If it was well designed, it should be unique and easy to do.

Document the hell out of the fact that you did this in whatever external documentation you are using.

Comment: "I can't change class names."

Comment: I read the question. But thank you, I should have mentioned I was telling him to do what he thinks he can't.

Comment: Change class name in two huge apps ... It represent a lot of work. It may introduce bugs. And I can't make the choice by myself. It would be better if I can avoid it.

Comment: You can't. If the name is unique enough it shouldn't create bugs. And it could take all of 5 min.

Comment: Names are not unique enough ^^ It's a symfony project with Propel, so there is Project and ProjectPeer for example.

Comment: You have a lot of work ahead of you. There is no easy way out of this pickle. My friend. I feel for you.

Comment: Ok. Thank for the answer. Let's go for a big rewrite :s

Comment: If you can find all the other classes that have Project in the name. Change those uniquer names first. Then just change Project. Then you can change the others back, if you want. Verbose Names are JOYFUL!

Comment: I was thinking of doing some kind of alias mess until I read this.
Excellent point.
Back to the drawing board...